# Kotlin Firebase set Multiple Values to Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

How can i set multiple values to firebase database using Kotlin? Something similar to the code below.

```
  val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
  val myRef = database.getReference("users")

  var ref = myRef.child(firebaseUser.uid)
  ref.setValue({ "username": username,
                            "email": email,
                            "rank": 0,
                            "message_count": 0,
                            "date_joined": date,
                            "purchase": false,
                            "initial_payment_option": "N/A",
                            "current_payment_option": "Free",
                            "subscription": "N/A",
                            "date_purchased": "N/A",
                            "family_discount": "N/A"})
```

Rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
     ".read": "true",
     ".write": "true",
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `HashMap<String, Object>` to contain all the keys and values you want to update.

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("username", username);
map.put("email", email);
// etc...
ref.setValue(map);
```

You can clean this up a bit with Kotlin's [hashMapOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html).

```
val map: HashMap<String, Object> = hashMapOf(
    "username" to username,
    "email" to email
)
```

Also [see the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for more examples like this.